# Looping through multidimensional array and label

Tags: javascript

Attempting to loop through the multidimensional array to have a result that looks like:
Gunman
STR : 6
DEF : 4
HP : 6
MAG : 5
SPD : 5
(Do excuse the nerdiness)

```
var rpg = {
    roles: ['Fighter', 'Magician', 'Rogue', 'Cleric', 'Ranger'],
    classes: [
        ['Paladin', 'Dark Knight', 'Dragoon'],
        ['Warlock', 'White Mage', 'Necromancer'],
        ['Thief', 'Ninja', 'Pirate'],
        ['Priest', 'Shaman', 'Alchemist'],
        ['Archer', 'Beast Master', 'Gunman']
    ],
    // stats format: strength, defense, health, magic, speed; scale 1-10
    statsFormat: ['STR', 'DEF', 'HP', 'MAG', 'SPD'],
    stats: [
        [
            [7, 8, 6, 3, 5],
            [9, 6, 7, 7, 3],
            [7, 6, 8, 8, 5],
        ],
        [
            [4, 5, 9, 9, 5],
            [2, 6, 8, 8, 5],
            [4, 5, 6, 10, 4],
        ],
        [
            [6, 3, 8, 2, 8],
            [6, 4, 7, 5, 9],
            [7, 5, 5, 2, 7],
        ],
        [
            [2, 5, 7, 7, 4],
            [3, 6, 6, 8, 4],
            [1, 8, 9, 6, 5],
        ],
        [
            [5, 6, 7, 4, 7],
            [7, 7, 6, 6, 7],
            [6, 4, 6, 5, 5],
        ]
    ],
    listFormat: function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.stats.length; i++) {
            var format = this.statsFormat[i];
            for (var j = 0; j < this.stats[i].length; j++) {
                console.log(this.classes[i][j]);
                for (var k = 0; k < this.stats[i][j].length; k++) {
                    console.log(format,":",this.stats[i][j][k]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

So far, I'm getting this:
Gunman
SPD : 6
SPD : 4
SPD : 6
SPD : 5
SPD : 5

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at how you have your loops set up in pseudocode

```
for each roleStats in stats, 0-5:
    format = statsFormat[item]
    for each classStats in roleStats:
        print class
        for each stat in classStats:
            print format ":" stat
```

Notice that you set the format at the same time you set the role. So each role is going to have exactly one stat format. You probably want your logic to look more like this:

```
for each roleStats in stats, 0-5:
    for each classStats in roleStats:
        print class
        for each stat in classStats, format in statFormats:
            print format ":" stat
```

Which can be expressed in Javascript as:

```
listFormat: function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.stats.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < this.stats[i].length; j++) {
            console.log(this.classes[i][j]);
            for (var k = 0; k < this.stats[i][j].length; k++) {
                var format = this.statsFormat[k];
                console.log(format,":",this.stats[i][j][k]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was it chief, thank you! And thank you for the clear explanation